# how to separate strings,special symbols and integers in the sql server?x

Tags: sql-server

this is the question  kumarpavanprashanth@@@123679

i have tried this

```
DECLARE @MyString varchar(1000) = 'kumarpavanprashanth@@@123679';

declare @Counter integer = 1;

declare @currChar char(1) = '';;

declare @charString varchar(1000) = '';

declare @intString varchar(1000) = '';



while (@Counter <= len(@MyString))
begin

 set @currChar = substring(@MyString,@Counter,1)
   
if isNumeric(@currChar) = 1
 set @intString = @intString + @currChar
   else
       set @charString = @charString + @currChar

  set @counter = @counter + 1
end

select @charString;
select cast(@intString as integer)
```

expected output:

in first column it should have kumar,pavan,prashanth

in second column it should have @,@,@

in third column it should have 1,2,3,6,7,9

Comment: You forgot to add the problem for which you are asking the question.

Comment: If `@intString` is containing number like `1,2,3,6,7,9` then you cannot do `select cast(@intString as integer)`   because `1,2,3,6,7,9` is not an integer.

Comment: current output shows as "kumarpavanprashanth@@@" and ",,,,,,1,2,3,6,7,9", which means you are always detecting the comma (',') as a numeric thing. Try changing that so it detect the comma as a word-separator!

Comment: sql server 2019

Comment: Perhaps YOU know that the string "kumarpavanprashanth" contains 3 words but there is no function in tsql that can separate that into 3 different words to add commas between them. You would need some sort of dictionary of names as a starting point - and a lot of custom code that will be difficult (perhaps impossible) to implement. Time to consult with your colleagues in your giant multinational consulting firm for direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you can define separate differently from all output types of strings. you  can use the below query: you have to use SQL 2016

SELECT
value
FROM STRING_SPLIT('kumar,pavan,prashanth/@,@,@/1,2,3,6,7,9', '/')

Comment: i want the results in separate columns